# Turn this into an if, else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

How can i turn this into an if else statement?

```
 try {
            antCopy= (Ant)super.clone();

        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {

        }
            return antCopy;
        }
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: `if () { } else { }` -- Complete it and you are done

Comment: The only way to know if an object is clonable is to try and clone it and see if it throws an exception. Using `Object#clone` is not recommended anyway due to its strange implementation. Better to write your own in your class.

Comment: I'm a serious noob....i'm thinking of dropping programming as a subject because i cannot get my head around it. Can you please explain a little simpler, if it is possible?

Comment: your coming up against knowledge that you need to acquire.  read more learn more.  look through the questions here for background on things that you can learn.  if your curious about programming you will get better.  if your doing it for a career but not interested then I would suggest you try something else that interests you more.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could check whether the class in question supports cloning. Classes implementing the Cloneable interface should provide a clone method. So you could do something like

```
if (this instanceof Cloneable) {
  return (Ant) super.clone();
} else {
  return antCopy;
}
```

However, implementing the Cloneable interface is still no **guarantee** that the class in question supports cloning. According to the API it should not throw a  CloneNotSupportedException, though.